# Where can I find documentation for 389-DS on SLES15?

Tags: sles, documentation, 389-ds

The version of 389-DS shipped with SLES15 SP3 is 1.4.4.19, and I wonder where the corresponding documentation can be found:

[389 Directory Server](https://directory.fedoraproject.org/) refers to [Product Documentation for Red Hat Directory Server 12](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/12) and I wonder whether the SLES version corresponds to any of Red Hat's versions 11 or 12, because those are the only product versions listed.

Or should I refer to [389 Directory Server Documentation](https://www.port389.org/docs/389ds/documentation.html)?
In [Release Notes](https://www.port389.org/docs/389ds/releases/release-notes.html) there are no versions 11 or 12.

I'm a bit confused.
SLES does not ship enough documentation to configure and use the product uses as replacement for OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Support suggested this link:

[389 Directory Server Documentation](https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/documentation.html)